# Fitsio Python Package Import Error - undefined symbol: fits_use_standard_strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I am trying to import fitsio version 1.2.1 on python 3.7.0. However, I receive the following error "ImportError:

```
/home/apc44/anaconda3/envs/pylab_py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fitsio/_fitsio_wrap.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: fits_use_standard_strings"
```

I have tried other versions of fitsio and python but have still been unable to resolve this issue. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try uininstall and re-installing it: `pip uninstall fitsio` and `pip install fitsio==1.2.1`

Comment: @meshkati thanks for the feedback. I tried that but unfortunately, I get the same error message.